# Solving a non-homogeneous ODE with boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE equation but my ODE skill is rusty. If you could link me to any material, I'd appreciate!

$$x - y(x) - xy'(x) = 0, y(r) = r$$

The equation is not separable and not homogeneous, so I'm not sure how to proceed. The answer given is very pretty:

$$y(x) = \frac{r^2 + x^2}{2x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x - y(x) - xy'(x) = 0, y(r) = r$$
$$x - (xy(x))' = 0$$
Integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is linear so you can apply the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) method to solve.

Equivalently, you could note that $y + xy' = (xy)'$, so that the equation can be integrated directly and rearranged for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is very easy.

Observe that,

$$d(xy) = xy' +y$$

Hence, given equation comes,

$$x- d(xy) =0$$
By integrating both side,we get:

$$\dfrac {x^2}2 -xy =c$$
(where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.)